# Sharepoint 2010 create new list item and open edit form

Tags: workflow

I have an issue regarding two lists that I am hoping someone can help with.

List B is created by a workflow from list A once the okay button is pressed, and it gets filled in with certain information such as title from the original list.

What I really need to do is to have the user fill in list A, click okay, then the workflow creates an item in list B with various info bought across(easy enough so far, however....) I then need the edit form for the newly generated list B item to open for the user.

Basically a workflow whereby the user goes from the List A edit form, creates list B item and moves the user to to the new list B item edit form.

Is anyone out there clever enough to see a way of doing this through SP Designer?

Any help would be appreciated

Many thanks

Wayne

Comment: In SP Designer - when you create a new item in a list - it gives you an output ID (The ID of the new item). 

Have you tried using some Javascript to throw up a "please wait" screen while the workflow runs, then sending the user to the new webaddress with the outputted ID from the workflow? If you store that ID in List A (New field of List ID from List B) and then have the Javascript re-direct you to a set webaddress - the EditForm.aspx page for that list with the ID. Web Address would end in EditForm.aspx?ID=[NewID#]

Comment: Thanks Josh, I'll be honest, I don't know anything about Java scripting, but its definately the redirect that I am struggling with. I can get the URL etc in designer, just not automatically open the form. Does this have to be a Java design?